# Why I get a very low accuracy with LSTM and pretrained word2vec?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, tf.keras, word-embedding

I'm working on a reviews classification model with only two categories 0 (negative) and 1 (positive). I'm using pre-trained word2vec from google with LSTM. The problem is I get an accuracy of around 50% where it should be around 83% according to this paper. I tried many different hyperparameters combination and still gets a horrible accuracy. I also tried to change the data preprocessing techniques and tried stemming but it hasn't resolved the problem

here's my code

```
X, y = read_data()
X = np.array(clean_text(X)) #apply data preprocessing  
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)

#converts text to sequence and add padding zeros
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
X_data = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen = length, padding = 'post')

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_data, y, test_size = 0.2)

#Load the word2vec model
word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILE, binary=True)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index))+1

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((nb_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
null_words = []
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if word in word2vec.wv.vocab:
        embedding_matrix[i] = word2vec.word_vec(word)
    else:
        null_words.append(word)

embedding_layer = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], # or len(word_index) + 1
                            embedding_matrix.shape[1], # or EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=701,
                            trainable=False)

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=2, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), workers = -1, verbose=1)

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, batch_size=64)
```

I also tried other optimizers like AdaMax and MSLE loss function and no matter how much I increase the epoch or change the batch size the accuracy never gets better. I'm just so confused if the problem isn't with the model and preprocessing where could it be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few things I noted,

Why do you have the `trainable=False` it is restricting your model, so that the model cannot finetune the embedding. Having to learn a problem using a fixed set of embedding is difficult than using trainable embedding. Therefore, try setting `trainable=True`.

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], # or len(word_index) + 1
                            embedding_matrix.shape[1], # or EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=701,
                            trainable=False)
```

Second problem is that you are using 2 units with sigmoid activation and `binary_crossentropy`. This combination doesn't work. You have two options.

```
model = Sequential()
...
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

### Option 1

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If you pick this option, note that your labels need to be `[sample size, 1]` shape.

### Option 2

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```